# why is there a gap at the bottom, padding/margin for no reason

Tags: html, css

i can't figure out why the text will not align with the middle of the div, which is what i believe to be causing the white space at the bottom of the page, i want the text in the middle (height) of the footer (both divs i have two to force each section of text to the edge of the page)

HTML :

```
 <div class="yellowfooterbackground">

 <div class="yellowfootercontent">

 <div class="yellowfootercontentleft">


 <p>IPS Fire & Security is a trading name of IPS Facilities - <u><a href="Terms-And-Conditions.html">Terms & Conditions</a></u></p>  

 </div>

 <div class="yellowfootercontentright">

 <p> Web Design & SEO by Raven </p>

 </div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
  .yellowfootercontent {
height: 30px;
width: 950px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;  
font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
font-size:12px;


}

  .yellowfootercontentleft {
height: 30px;
width: 475px;
float: left;
text-align: left;


 }

 .yellowfootercontentright {
height: 30px;
width: 475px;
text-align: right;
float: right;
 }
```

Comment: Add a jsFiddle to your question

Comment: Have you noticed the `</div` that is missing its `>`?

Comment: You are also missing a closing `<p>` in your yellowfootercontentleft div

Comment: @haxtbh — The end tag for p elements is optional.

Comment: Use the developer tools shipped with your browser (normally F12) and run an "Inspect Element".  You should be able to see exactly where the problem is. generally.

Comment: You code above is invalid. Not only the `>` is missing but also the closing `</p>`. If I correct it, everything works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/KittMedia/feE22/

Comment: thanks for the help. fixed the div closing tag and the p closing tag. still got a gap at the bottom and the text still isnt sitting in the middle, slightly low, any ideas?

Comment: @Quentin Depends on his doctype. In HTML5 this is true only if the p element is followed by certain tags. None of which he has used.

Comment: @haxtbh — It is true of all versions of HTML. (It only isn't true in XHTML, and even there it only matters when in XML parsing mode where it would trigger a yellow screen of death, which clearly isn't the case here). The "certain tags" you mention include the div end tag, which does follow the paragraph, so you are wrong there.

Comment: i have updated the OP so all the html issues were fixed and i have cleaned up the CSS Code too, the problem is now simpler i think, the text doesnt align in the middle of the div, it appears to hang over the edge slightly which appears to be why the white spacing at the bottom is happening, how do i make the text align with the middle of the div?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.yellowfooterbackground {
margin-top:-12px;
width:100%;
height:30px;
background-color:#ffd602;
padding-bottom:12px;
}

 .yellowfootercontent {
height: 30px;
width: 950px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;  
font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
font-size:12px;
line-height:40px;
}

.yellowfootercontentleft {
height: 30px;
width: 475px;
float: left;
text-align: left;
}

.yellowfootercontentright {
height: 30px;
width: 475px;
text-align: right;
float: right;
line-height:42px;
}
```

I've added a few line-height property. I not sure it is the smartest way but somehow, it solved the problem. See [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/feE22/1/)

Comment: So what is the problem now? The gap at bottom still there or?

Comment: gap is still at the bottom and also the text isnt in the middle of the div

Comment: i have removed line height attribute and made it less worse if that makes sense, text is still at bottom of div with white gap.

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/feE22/1/ . I've added a few line height and there is no gap at the bottom of text. If it's working, could you mark it as correct answer?

Comment: What do you mean by not working? It worked in my jsfiddle. Would you mind to post me a link to your website or jsfiddle or whatever?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52095/discussion-between-sn1dan-and-newbie)